# Conflicting Hover Pseudo Classes

Tags: css, css-selectors, hover

I have a situation where I am modifying an element using a hover pseudo class both when its parent is hovered over and when it is hover over. Unfortunately, they have a conflicting property (both trying to define the property `transform`), which is why -- I assume -- the scaling is not working when the button is hovered over but the cursor change is. Is there a work around using just CSS?

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
 }

#action-panel {
    align-items: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
}

#action-panel:hover .action-button {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.action-button {
    background-color: lightblue;
    border-radius: 25px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out, transform 200ms ease-in-out;
    transform: translateX(calc(100% + 20px));
    width: 50px;
}

.action-button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: translateX(0) scale(1.2);
}

.action-button span {
    font-size: 30px;
    left: 50%;
    position: relative;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="action-panel">
    <div class="action-button"><span class="material-icons">3d_rotation</span></div>
    <div class="action-button"><span class="material-icons">compare_arrows</span></div>
    <div class="action-button"></div>
</div>
```

**Note:**

If you cannot tell from the code, you need to move your cursor to the middle of the right edge to see the effects I am describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increased the specificity of the following style by adding `#action-panel` before it. In your code the hover styles of parent were overriding the hover styles of child.

```
 #action-panel .action-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateX(0) scale(1.2);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#action-panel {
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
}

#action-panel:hover .action-button {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.action-button {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out, transform 200ms ease-in-out;
  transform: translateX(calc(100% + 20px));
  width: 50px;
}

#action-panel .action-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateX(0) scale(1.2);
}

.action-button span {
  font-size: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="action-panel">
  <div class="action-button"><span class="material-icons">3d_rotation</span></div>
  <div class="action-button"><span class="material-icons">compare_arrows</span></div>
  <div class="action-button"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, I actually tried this, but I defined `#action-panel .action-button:hover` before `#action-panel:hover .action-button` and it didn't work.